# SyntaxError: Invalid syntax? Eval()

Tags: python

Basically I am doing a POC against python `eval` security issue, but I am getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "exploit.py", line 11, in <module>
  a = paste()
 File "exploit.py", line 6, in paste
  if eval('%s > 1' % a):
 File "<string>", line 1
import os;os.system('pwd') > 1
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Code:

```
import datetime

def paste():
    a = "import os;os.system('pwd')"
    if eval('%s > 1' % a):
       print a
    else:
       #create_brew(request.json)
       return None, 201
a = paste()
print a
```

can anyone help me how to import libraries in-line?

Comment: Compare to `__import__("os").system("pwd")`, which is purely an expression.

Answer (score 1):

`eval` works in expressions.
Use `exec` to execute a statement [`import` is a statement]

Also note, you cannot assign exec to a variable.

```
>> exec('import os;data = os.getcwd()')
>> print(data)
>> # /path/of/you/cwd
```

You may use the variable `data` to continue with your tests.

---

Taking the liberty to edit your code as follow:

```
def paste():
    data = None
    exec('import os;data = os.getcwd()')
    if data:
        return data
    else:
         return None, 201


a = paste()

print(a)
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? you mean like `a = "exec(import os;os.system('pwd'))"`?

Comment: Updated my answer. You cannot assign it as you do with eval. 
Note that eval will return None nevertheless.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval